# Password encryption function is not working in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

The function is not working in Oracle 11g.

I did use the same function in the Oracle 8i database and it is working.

```
create or replace FUNCTION chePass( pa char) RETURN char is a varchar2(50);
b char(1);
c number(4):=0;
H varchar2(30);
BEGIN

  if pa is null then
    return null;
  end if;
  a:=rtrim(pa);
   for i in 1..length(a) loop
   b:=substr(a,i,1);
   c:=ASCII(b);

    IF C <= 27*i then
       c:=(255+c)- (27*i);
    else
       c:=c - (27*i);
    end if;
         H:= H || chr(c);  

   end loop;
return H; 
END;
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Define "not working".  Are you getting an error?  Is the function not returning what you expect?  What do you expect it to return vs. what is it returning?  Is the character set the same in both databases?  And, gee golly, I hope that you're not using this to obfuscate real passwords in a real production environment.  Because this is **not** encryption.

Comment: Hope Bruce Schneier doesn't see this "encryption" of yours. Speaking of which here is some way to do _real_ encryption to keep Bruce busy: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm